# Can I set the value of a String in Java without using a constructor?

Tags: java, string

How-Do/Can I set the value of a String object in Java (without creating a new String object)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are no "set" methods on `String`. Strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) in Java. To change the value of a `String` variable you need to assign a different string to the variable. You can't change the existing string.

> (without creating a new String object)

Assigning doesn't create a new object - it copies the reference. Note that even if you write something like this:

```
s = "hello";
```

it *won't* create a new string object each time it is run. The string object will come from the string pool.

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is no way to do that in Java, the String objects are immutable by default.

In fact, that's one of the reason why using the `"+"` concatenation operator like `"str1" + "str2"` is terribly inefficient, because what it does is copy every string in order to produce a third one.

Depending on your need you should consider using `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable so you cannot change the value of an already created string.

Answer (score 2):

The String object is immutable in Java so any changes create a new String object. Use a StringBuilder if you want to make changes to a string like object without creating new objects. As a bonus the StringBuilder allows you to preallocate additional memory if you know something about the eventual length of your string.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question because i have to set a string within an "enclosing type" - an anonymous type. But all variables i want to set inside and use outside must be final.

The simple solution is to **use StringBuilder** - it's an mutable String.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your definition of object. If you mean the reference, no. A reference is always created. If you mean the memory used by the characters, sure.

Strings are interned (if possible) which means that in an assignment:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";
```

there are 2 references (pointers to a memory location), but `Hello` is in memory on only 1 place. This is one of the reasons Strings can't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can access the internal char array via reflection. But it's usually a bad idea to do so. More on http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t16714.html.

Comment: It is **always** a bad idea.  If you need mutable strings, use `StringBuilder` instances instead.